# One hot encoding for multi level categorical data-set

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

My Dataset is as following:

Symptoms (X)   ::                                  Condition (Y)
fever, headache, blindnes          ::                 wagner syndrom
tooth pain,fever , sweet urine   ::                 buri buri diseases
blindness,nose bleed,fever     :: Taylor syndrome

where X are the features and Y are my labels. i would like to encode X into one-hot-encoding matrix. panda's get_dummies cant handle multiple values in one column but if i will split X into multiple columns i will lose the ability to encode the symptoms to the same one-hot matrix

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with Sklearn CountVectoriser, each word is a column, row an observation. If you set the binary tag to true, for each row if the word is present it will be represented as a 1 for that row|column. Set binary to False and its the number of times that word is present in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, your requirement is not one-hot encoding. For one hot encoding, there is only feature with value 1, all of others are 0. So you can consider to split your X to multiple features, then use [OrdinalEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder) in sklearn.